# how to search record in mysql with special characters

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL where in table i have three record like this

```
ABC10%DEF
XYZ10GKSLK
CKALK143LK
```

Now i want to search where it finds word '10%' in record. so here it should return only "ABC10%DEF". But it shows me two record "ABC10%DEF" and "XYZ10GKSLK" because in search term i have used % sign. How to ignore this "%" in search result so that it can consider % as searching character rather than wildcard characters.

Comment: **Hint:**` `LOCATE, SUBSTR`.`like '%10\%%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shuould  escape the %

```
 select * from my_table 
 where my_column like '%10\%%'
```

Comment: if you don't mind change both quotes even like '%10\%%'

Comment: @jothi  thank  ..  a  typo